# failsave offline logout handle tokens

Tags: authentication, jwt, offline, logout, refresh-token

**Summary what I would like to achieve:**

I would like to have a short lived access token stored in a web worker and a long lived refresh token stored in a httponly cookie and still be able to failsave logout offline.

**Current implementation:**

In my Web App I am using an access token and a refresh token for authentication. Both tokens are JWT.

The access token is short lived and stored in a web worker. Compared to sessionStorage this seems to be relatively save according to several blogposts I read. Compared to a cookie the benefit is also, that my access token is automatically deleted when the tab/browser is closed without further ado.
So far so good.

But with introducing the refresh token this leads the whole thing ad absurum. The refresh token must be retained even if the browser is closed. For security reasons I decided to store it in an httponly cookie.

Hence, the httponly cookie cannot be deleted by the client itself via javascript. That means, on logout, my client needs a valid internet connection to let my server know the cookie has to be removed. I cannot assure that, hence have to warn my user "your logout did not work" - which sounds like a pretty bad user experience. In my opinion, a logout has to be fail safe.

**Possible solutions (not satisfying in my opinion):**

1.: Store the refresh token as cookie with httponly=false. Then, I can also delete it client side on logout without internet connection. But why would I protect my short lived access token stronger than my long lived refresh token? That does not make sense to me.

2.: Use an access token that is ONLY removed on logout, NOT on browser close (basically store it in a cookie with httponly=false). When validating the refresh token, I then can require an access token that has at least a valid signature (but might be expired). If the user logs out, I can remove the access token client side. But if the user closes the browser, the access token remains and can be used to two-factor-validate my refresh token even if it'sexpired. However, this stronger exposes my access token compared to the web-worker approach.

**Can you point me in a direction what would make sense here?**